# JQuery var is undefined at first click but defined after second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, click

I'm trying to call data using ajax but I only get the data after the second click. I have add console.log to realize that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var target = "http://neoldes/cs/Satellite?pagename=SiteEntry_LT_EM/ConsumptionStatistics/ConsumptionPerHour";
    var component;

    $("header.mod_info_top").on("click", function() {
        $(this).siblings(".cs_consumption_hour").empty();
        loadConsPerHour( target ).success(function (data) {
            component = data;
        });
        console.log("component");
        console.log(component);
        $(this).next().append(component);
    });

});

function loadConsPerHour( dir ){
    return $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        data: { "accountNumber": $("#count_id").val(),"addressService": $("#addressService").val(), "department": $("#department").val(), "municipality": $("#municipality").val(), "borderTrade": $("#borderTrade").val() }
    });
}
```

This is the retun in the console
firs click:

```
component
undefined
```

second click:

```
component
<div id="component"> ... { more html } ...</div>
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if I can improve my code.

Comment: Ajax operations are **asynchronous**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the console.log() function is executed before the AJAX is completed.
You will have to do call console.log() when AJAX is done, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var target = "http://neoldes/cs/Satellite?pagename=SiteEntry_LT_EM/ConsumptionStatistics/ConsumptionPerHour";
    var component;

    $("header.mod_info_top").on("click", function() {
        var targetElement = $(this);
        $(this).siblings(".cs_consumption_hour").empty();
        loadConsPerHour( target ).success(function (data) {
            component = data;
            console.log("component");
            console.log(component);
            targetElement.next().append(component);
        });
    });

});

function loadConsPerHour( dir ){
    return $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        data: { "accountNumber": $("#count_id").val(),"addressService": $("#addressService").val(), "department": $("#department").val(), "municipality": $("#municipality").val(), "borderTrade": $("#borderTrade").val() }
    });
}
```

It will log:

```
component
<div id="component"> ... { more html } ...</div>
```

Comment: In this way it's loggin correctly at first time but never append the data. Maybe the object $(this) isn't the same within the function?

Comment: I need to append the data in `$("header.mod_info_top")` but if I move `$(this).next().append(component);` inside `loadConsPerHour` nothing happens.

Comment: Now I want to animate the append data, so I'm doing  `targetElement.next().append(component).slideDown("slow");` but the animation is not appearing. What can be the reason?

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try move the append code to inside of success callback.

```
$("header.mod_info_top").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".cs_consumption_hour").empty();
    loadConsPerHour( target ).success(function (data) {
        component = data;
        console.log("component");
        console.log(component);
        $(this).next().append(component);
    });
});
```